# How to add an icon of app that I have downloaded in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04

I have downloaded Webstorm, but accidentally I did not see an icon. Then I just wrote a command "bash webstorm.sh" and then Webstorm run. But I really don't want to run WS with this method. Help me

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 2):

just create a desktop file ( a file with desktop extension, for example my_app.desktop) and then move this file under "~/.local/share/applications" or under "/usr/share/applications" (if you are a member of sudoers and you can run a command with sudo).

your desktop file should be similar to this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Webstorm
Comment=terminal app
Exec="bash webstorm.sh" 
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=path_to_icon
Categories=IDE;
```